# "Flatten" List<Tuple<<T>,<T>>> into List<T>

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a list of tuples, the objects in the tuple are both the same type. The data structure of a list of tuples is needed until we get to error handling. To optimize error handling, I would like to flatten the tuples into a single list to allow for duplicate checking:

For instance if I had `List<Tuple<string,string>>()` (my types are more complex but the idea should hold):

`[<"Tom","Dick">, <"Dick","Harry">, <"Bob","John">]`

I would like to end up with:

`["Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Bob", "John"]`

I know I could do this with:

```
List<string> stringList = List<string>();
Foreach(var item in tupleList){
  stringList.Add(item.Item1);
  stringList.Add(item.Item2);
}
stringList = stringList.Distinct();
```

But I am hoping for a more efficient way, perhaps something built into Linq. There is no guarantee of duplicates, but due to the performance cost of error handling, I would rather handle each only once.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you have. I would just opt for using a `HashSet<string>` instead so I could get rid of the `Distinct()` call.

Comment: You can do this with Linq, but that doesn't mean it's better: `tupleList.SelectMany(t => new string[] {t.Item1, t.Item2}).Distinct().ToList()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need distinct items without order - use [`HashSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383091(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
HashSet<string> stringList = new HashSet<string>();
foreach(var item in tupleList){
  stringList.Add(item.Item1);
  stringList.Add(item.Item2);
}
```

You can do similar code with LINQ, but it will not be faster (and probably not better looking as you need to convert `Tuple` to enumerable for most operations). You can try `Aggregate` if you really looking for LINQ.

Comment: Being Linq doesn't matter, Linq is just used commonly in the system and available if it's better. With how much Linq can do with enumerables I was hoping it had a way to flatten. Order doesn't matter, the result will be iterated over again anyways.

Comment: This is the best way I can think of to do this. You could do it with LINQ a few ways but it would be far less readable and probably not as efficient.

Comment: @Andrew It does. And the question you downvoted and was later deleted by the author showed you how - using `SelectMany`.  `stringList.SelectMany(t => new[] {t.Item1, t.Item2})` returns `IEnumerable<string>` which means you can call `Distinct` on and get what you're looking for.

Comment: I voted to undelete the answer showing `SelectMany`, I'm not sure why both answers got downvotes - while I don't think creating many arrays is "efficient" way, but definitely solid LINQ way. (Plus comment by @Andrew on that deleted question is just wrong - possibly explaining why one downvoted...)

Answer (score 4):

Its simple by using linq SelectMany method

```
var tupleList = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new Tuple<string, string>(i.ToString(), "just for example")); // tuples
var trg = tupleList.SelectMany(t => new[] { t.Item1, t.Item2 }).Distinct();
```

One line, however still not a tetris in one line Ж)

Answer (score 2):

As a slight variation on the above you could also do this:

```
HashSet<string> hash= new HashSet<string>();
tupleList.ForEach(l => hash.UnionWith(new string[] { l.Item1, l.Item2 }));
```

Although I like the `SelectMany` example in the comments of the question

Comment: The issue with SelectMany and UnionWith is they both create an array per tuple, I think that's likely to perform worse than iteration.\

Comment: @Andrew you are right, however these arrays are creating on the stack but not on the heap, so they are not going to be destroyed by GC but as a function returns, its optimized by CLR. By using it you gain easy way to parallel processing in one line - tupleList.AsParallel().SelectMany(t => new[] { t.Item1, t.Item2 }).Distinct().ToArray();